# Trouble using AsyncElasticsearch with RequestsHttpConnection

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, aiohttp

I'm running Python 3.8 and getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/_async/transport.py", line 297, in perform_request
status, headers, data = await connection.perform_request(

TypeError: object tuple can't be used in 'await' expression
```

It would be great if anyone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
from elasticsearch import AsyncElasticsearch, AIOHttpConnection
```

Importing connection class `AIOHttpConnection` and using it in ES client, will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`RequestsHttpConnection` can only make sync requests.

This class is not compatible with the `AsyncElasticsearch` client.

The async client at this time can only use `AIOHttpConnection` connection class.

```
from elasticsearch import AsyncElasticsearch, AIOHttpConnection
```

Reference: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1333